# Como pegar a porcentagem atual de um download?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Quero pegar o valor da porcentagem de uma requisição ajax em um servidor externo. Como fazer?

```
$("#uptade_space_disk").click(function(){
     var url = "/calcular-espaco-em-disco"
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'script', 
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loader").show();
            $("#uptade_space_disk").hide();
        },                                      
        success: function() {
        },
        error: function() {
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 5):

O que você está procurando é um evento de progresso, ou seja que é atualizado conforme o download é processado. Adaptei seu código baseado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20984502/1850091):

```
$("#uptade_space_disk").click(function(){
  var url = "/calcular-espaco-em-disco"
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'script', 
    beforeSend: function () {
      $("#loader").show();
      $("#uptade_space_disk").hide();
    },                                      
    success: function () {},
    error: function () {},
    xhr: function () {
      // pega o objeto XmlHttpRequest que o jQuery está usando
      var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr() ;
      // vincula a função ao evento
      xhr.onprogress = function(evt){
        $("#loader").text(Math.round(evt.loaded*100/evt.total) + '%');
      };
      // retorna o objeto para o jQuery
      return xhr;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Gustavo, deu um problema ai.. Coloquei console.log(Math.round(evt.loaded*100/evt.total) + '%') e ele só mostra quando esta 100% e não atualizou o #loader.. oque sera que é?

Comment: [Nem todo navegador suporta esse evento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_Compatibility) (aliás só hoje fiquei sabendo que ele existe). Sobre atualizar o `#loader` eu dei um chute sobre como o seu código está organizado, qualquer coisa tente usar `.html()`.